# How to remove files in different folders via terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to remove files that are located in different folders.

I have

```
find /project/test/ -name "*junk-12.png" -delete
```

to delete anything like

```
`project/test/bad/testjunk-12.png` and `project/test/good/gojunk-12.png`
```

However, the files are still there after I ran the command.

I was hoping if anyone here can help me out on this one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it print the files if you leave out the delete option?

Comment: Is *project* really in the */* directory or is the leading slash a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the following should work:

```
find ./project/test -name "*junk-12.png" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Your command should work too, if you replace `/project/test` by `./project/test`.

Answer (score -1):

you may try following

rm -f `find /project/test/ -name "*junk-12.png"`

Comment: This will horribly fail if any of the paths found contains a space. A safer alternative would be to remove the files and folders found through the exec option of find. Please note that you have to escape back ticks or indent code by 4 spaces.