# How to remove multiple files in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

My preview post is about removing the single name file in the system but I actually need to remove big range of files.

previous post

[How to remove files in different folders via terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/598685/how-to-remove-files-in-different-folders)

For example

They are `junkImg-5.png` to `junkImg-60.png`, ,meaning there are `junkImg-30`,`junkImg-45`...etc.

Are there any quick command to remove them in the command line?

I have tried

```
find /project/test/ -name 'junkImg-5*' -exec rm -f {} \ ;
```

but it's way too slow and I have so many images. Is there a way that linux can specify the range? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `meaning there are junkImg-30, junkImg45...` - can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I mean there are many files named like junkImg-10,junkImg-11,junkImg-12 all the wy to junkImg-60

Comment: Just `rm junkImg-* -f` doesn't work? -f prevents the "are you sure" message.

Comment: I need to keep junkImg-1 to junkImg-4, so rm junkImg-* won't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) to delete the range of files:

```
rm /project/test/junkImg-{5..60}.png
```

This will remove junkImg files 5 though 60, with only one `rm` process. You can also first substitute the `rm` command with `ls` to make sure it is selecting the files you want, then replace it again with `rm`.

Comment: If all images are in the same directory, this is definitely the way to go. The link to the OP's previous post ([How to remove files in different folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/598685/how-to-remove-files-in-different-folders)) made me think otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Find uses [Shell Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Shell-Pattern-Matching.html) for the *-name* predicate, so you can use the *-or* predicate and these patterns:

```
find DIRECTORY -name 'junkImg-[5-9].png' -or -name 'junkImg-[1-6]?.png' -delete
```

You can also exclude the first four files by using the *-not* predicate:

```
find DIRECTORY -name 'junkImg-*.png' -not -name 'junkImg-[1-4].png' -delete
```

To test if the commands work properly, always run them without *-delete* first. This will list the files instead of removing them.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a new `rm` command for each deletion. That is not the fastest way. You only need to do that if you have that many files that you can not list them all in one go.

TO make things faster, either:

1. change the `-exec rm` with `-ls` and pipe it though xargs. Toss in a -print0 if you expect some of the filenames to be difficult (e.g. have a space in them).
2. Or better, use finds build in `-delete`.